# Jquery POST JSON data to Python backend

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, json, tornado

I would like to send some data from jQuery to a Tornado Python backend.

Here is simple example:

```js
$.ajax({
    url: '/submit_net',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify({"test_1":"1","test_2":"2"}),
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    },
    error: function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }

});
```

Here is the Python code:

```
class submit_net(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        data_json = self.request.arguments
        print data_json
```

When I click the *submit* button then the Python backend retrieves following dictionary

```
{'{"test_1":"1","test_2":"2"}': ['']}
```

but I would like to retrieve exactly the same dictionary as jQuery sends:

```
{"test_1":"1","test_2":"2"}
```

Could you help me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried without stringify?

Comment: @Jai: no, then they'd not be sending JSON. This is a problem to be solved on the *receiving end*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`request.arguments` should only be used for *form encoded data*. Use [`request.body`](http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/httputil.html#tornado.httputil.HTTPServerRequest.body) to access the JSON raw data and decode with the [`json` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html):

```
import json

data_json = self.request.body
data = json.loads(data_json)
```

`request.body` contains *bytes*, which is fine in Python 2, but if you are using Python 3 you need to decode those to Unicode first. Get the request character-set with [`cgi.parse_header()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/cgi.html#cgi.parse_header):

```
from cgi import parse_header

content_type = self.request.headers.get('content-type', '')
content_type, params = parse_header(content_type)
charset = params.get('charset', 'UTF8')
data = json.loads(data_json.decode(charset))
```

This defaults to the UTF-8 character set, which as a default is only valid for *JSON* requests; other request content types would need to be handled differently.

You may want to make it clear that you are sending a JSON body by setting the content type:

```js
$.ajax({
    url: '/submit_net',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify({"test_1":"1","test_2":"2"}),
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    },
    error: function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

and verify in your Tornado POST handler that that content type is being used before trying to decode the POST as JSON:

```
content_type = self.request.headers.get('content-type', '')
content_type, params = parse_header(content_type)
if content_type.lower() != 'application/json':
    # return a 406 error; not the right content type
    # ...

charset = params.get('charset', 'UTF8')
data = json.loads(data_json.decode(charset))
```

The `$.ajax` `dataType` parameter is only needed when you are returning JSON from Python  back to jQuery; it tells jQuery to decode the response for you. This is not strictly needed even then, as a `application/json` response Content-Type header is enough.